# PowerShell: replacing AD DS ACLs

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I am looking for a code sample showing how a permission set on a given Active Directory object (in my case an Organizational Unit) could be modified in a way where permissions for a given security principal would be replaced by another security principal, similar to what the resource kit utility [`subinacl`](http://ss64.com/nt/subinacl.html) is doing for filesystem and registry ACLs with the `subinacl [...] replace=olduser=newuser [...]` syntax.

I tried coming up with an elegant way using a sequence of `Get-ACL(Get-ADOrganizationalUnit [...]).DistinguishedName` and `Set-ACL -InputObject [...]` calls, but seem unable to figure out how to replace the user/group identifiers in the ACL object returned by `Get-ACL` by the desired ones.

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing in [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/480802/copying-ou-permissions-from-an-existing-security-group-to-a-new-security-group/482605) could be considered "elegant" :) -- give it a look. If it's not similar to what you need, could you clarify in your question? I think you may be having issue creating the new ACE object to apply onto the ACL. I'd be happy to provide a more generic version as an example.

Comment: @jscott this looks promising, thank you. I am going to see what I can build around the core.

Comment: Wow, I'm flattered, thank you.  It was very, very generous of you to bounty this.

Comment: @jscott it helped me finish my work, so it is my turn to thank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a generic `CopyDsAcl` function, [hosted on my bitbucket](http://hg.jasonscott.org/copydsacl), to perform such Directory Services ACL copies.  You are welcome to use it as a reference or tool. Feedback is most welcome.

To replace the ACEs for "olduser" on OU "someOU" with ACEs for "newuser", you could do the following:

```
CopyDsAcl -sourcePrincipal (Get-ADUser olduser) -sourceObject (Get-ADOrganizationalUnit "OU=someOU,DC=example,DC=com") -targetPrincipal (Get-ADUser newuser) -removeSourceAces
```

These articles were most helpful in finding a way to tie .NET, AD and ACL mangling all together:

- [ActiveDirectoryAccessRule Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/es318t38.aspx)
- [AddAccessRule method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.directoryobjectsecurity.addaccessrule(v=vs.90).aspx)
- [RemoveAccessRuleSpecific method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.directoryobjectsecurity.removeaccessrulespecific(v=vs.90).aspx)